# Can someone explain to me what happens at a certain part of this code? (MIPS/ASSEMBLY)

Tags: mips, subroutine, mars-simulator

Sorry that I keep asking questions I feel so bad.

```
  .data
.align 4
Table: .space 24
msg1: .asciiz "Please insert an integer: "
msg2: .asciiz " "
msg3: .asciiz "\nVector contents: "
.text
.globl main
main:

addi $s0,$zero,5
addi $t0,$zero,0
in:
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg1
syscall
li $v0,5
syscall
add $t1,$t0,$zero
sll $t1,$t0,2
add $t3,$v0,$zero
sw $t3,Table ( $t1 )
addi $t0,$t0,1
slt $t1,$s0,$t0
beq $t1,$zero,in

la $a0,Table
addi $a1,$s0,1 #a1=6
#call buble_sort
jal buble_sort

#print table
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg3
syscall
la $t0,Table
#s0=5
add $t1,$zero,$zero
printtable:
lw $a0,0($t0)
li $v0,1
syscall
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg2
syscall
addi $t0,$t0,4
addi $t1,$t1,1
slt $t2,$s0,$t1
beq $t2,$zero,printtable

li $v0,10
syscall

buble_sort:
#a0=address of table
#a1=sizeof table
add $t0,$zero,$zero #counter1( i )=0

loop1:
addi $t0,$t0,1 #i++
bgt $t0,$a1,endloop1 #if t0 < a1 break;

add $t1,$a1,$zero #counter2=size=6
loop2:

bge $t0,$t1,loop1 #j < = i

#slt $t3,$t1,$t0
#bne $t3,$zero,loop1

addi $t1,$t1,-1 #j--

mul $t4,$t1,4 #t4+a0=table[j]
addi $t3,$t4,-4 #t3+a0=table[j-1]
add $t7,$t4,$a0 #t7=table[j]
add $t8,$t3,$a0 #t8=table[j-1]
lw $t5,0($t7)
lw $t6,0($t8)

bgt $t5,$t6,loop2

#switch t5,t6
sw $t5,0($t8)
sw $t6,0($t7)
j loop2

endloop1:
jr $ra
```

This IS NOT my code, I am simply just trying to understand what happens at a certain spot

Few questions.. What does ALIGN and .SPACE do?   How do you know how much space you need to allocate?

I understand most of the code (at least I think I do) But I'm stumped on  the loop1 and loop2 label.

MAIN QUESTION: 
My question is  when does the program ever GO back to loop1? If the counter for loop 1 starts at 1 (from addi) it needs to reach 6 to break.  When is it ever called to increment +1 because in loop2

```
bge $t0,$t1,loop1
```

This is NEVER going to be true unless $t0 is incremented?   $t1 value is the value of the array which is 6.
I don't see the program ever going back to the loop1 ... so can someone explain to me how it does?  The counter Has to reach 6 somehow because the program works fine.  (Printing out assorted array from least to greatest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the MARS simulator (yes, I know "simulator" is redundant and I'll fix it as soon as people stop referring to ATM machines and PIN numbers), `.align 4` will set the alignment to a multiple of sixteen (`24`). For example, it will ensure that `Table` will be on a sixteen-byte boundary like `0000`, `4110`, or `fff0`. Alignment is usually because some CPUs work faster if `n`-byte data elements are aligned on an `n`-byte boundary (some will even raise a hardware exception if alignment is violated) but I'm not sure that's the case here since an alignment of sixteen is pretty "wide".

`.space 24` simply allocates twenty-four bytes of space, in this case to hold the `Table` data structure.

It appears that your initial loop (inputting the data) has a limit of six entries, based on the interaction between `$s0` and `$t0`.

The instruction sequence:

```
slt $t1,$s0,$t0
beq $t1,$zero,in
```

will branch back to `in` as long as `$s0` (= `5`) is less than `$t0`, so `$t0` iterates from `0` to `5` inclusive (six items).

*That* limit is how you would decide how much space to allocate (six 32-bit values would be twenty-four bytes).

---

And that loop *will* work. You state that:

> `bge $t0,$t1,loop1` : This is NEVER going to be true unless `$t0` is incremented?

but, in fact, that's not quite right, it could *also* become true if you decrement `$t1` and, lo and behold, there it is on the third code (`non-':'`) line below:

```
loop2:
bge $t0,$t1,loop1 #j < = i
:
addi $t1,$t1,-1 #j--
:
j loop2
```

Thinking in terms of pseudo-code, it's the same as these two loops (in terms of how many iterations are done):

```
limit = 10, value = 0      limit = 10, value = 0
while value < limit:       while value < limit:
    value = value + 1          limit = limit - 1
```

Comment: I still don't understand how would you know how MUCH space you need?  I'm assuming it's more optimal to only use the space you need and not put a random high number?

Comment: inputting the data has a limit of 6.  Or at least the code asks for a number 6 times.  But if I changed the space to a smaller amount, it will let me input a number, it just won't output the text to ask me for the number if that makes sense.

In any case, thanks for the help :D It starting to make a little more sense to me.. Now I'm just hoping someone can answer the my question about the actual code +_+ .  Thank you!

Comment: @Jpyo, that's because, if you allow space for five numbers and input/store six, the sixth will overwrite `msg1`, the next thing in memory.

Comment: Oh my god lol. I can't believe I didn't see it.  I mean I saw it but I ignored it because of the fact that I was searching so hard to see where $t0 incremented  that I didn't bother to check if $t1 decremented though I had written it down on my paper x_o!!!

Comment: I have  a tendency to only look at 1 possibility and forget about others hence, I mess up a lot when writing code because I don't see the other ways to approach it.  Thank you!  If  I could upvote a million times I would.

Comment: No problems, @Jpyo, glad I could help. But, if you could upvote a million times, so could everyone else, and I'd _still_ be nowhere near Jon Skeet's rep :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Actually, `.align 4` is an alignment to 16 bytes. `.align n` aligns to a `2^n` byte boundary.

Comment: @Konrad, I stand corrected and have updated the answer. Thanks for the heads-up.